# Extra Gradle tasks in Spring project

Tags: java, spring

Fairly new to Gradle.  Newer to Spring.  I understand the creation of Gradle tasks, how to compose them, and how to create Groovy plugins but it seems that there's more going on than what's in the project.

I've got a Spring REST service with a build.gradle file but I notice that once everything syncs, there are a TON of tasks in my Gradle plugin that I can't seem to find anywhere in the project.  Such as: cleanEclipse, installApp, startScripts and many others.

Are these added by something more global?  If so, what is it that defines the creation of all of these tasks?

IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.1
Gradle 2.2.1
Windows 7

Comment: Check if you have something like "apply plugin: 'eclipse'" in your build.gradle

Comment: Really -- use maven, not gradle, because gradle really sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra tasks that you see look like Gradle tasks are injected into the project by various plugins.

For example, the `eclipse` plugin includes tasks such as `eclipse`, `cleanEclipse` etc.

Here is a listing of all the standard Gradle plugins that come bundled with Gradle: https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/standard_plugins.html

Each of these has a list of tasks/properties that it injects into the project. Third party plugins would also do the same and their corresponding documentation should have information regarding these.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow.  So could these plugins be added from somewhere in the Spring Jars that are downloaded?  I've noticed that if I just make a plain vanilla Gradle project with no Spring, no tasks show up other than what I've made in build.gradle.

Comment: Ah - it finally clicked.  demostene made a comment above about the "apply plugin" lines and now I see exactly what you're saying.  These are preconfigured with Gradle and not necessarily the result of a downloaded dependency.  Major light bulb moment.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be added if others plugins are applied in your project, for example eclipse plugin or application plugin.